# How to populate recyclerview with compex json data using retrofit?

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, openweathermap

please advise. I have a complex json object which I get requesting to openweathermap API using Retrofit and GSONConverterFactory. I have a trouble requesting forecast for 5 days, I can't populate my Recyclerview with the data, something goes wrong. I can't get what should I write in the onResponse method of Retrofit callback.

Retrofit requests are all with code 200 and message OK. So trouble is not in this area.

Thank you in advance!

Here is structure of Json object

[image: Structure of Json object]

WeatherData is a root Object which I get parsing my Json, please find the code below. All the code for it (as well as for other POJO's is imported from jsonschema2pojo:

```
public class WeatherData {

@SerializedName("coord")
@Expose
private Coord coord;
@SerializedName("weather")
@Expose
private List<Weather> weather = null;
@SerializedName("base")
@Expose
private String base;
@SerializedName("main")
@Expose
private Main main;
@SerializedName("visibility")
@Expose
private Integer visibility;
@SerializedName("wind")
@Expose
private Wind wind;
@SerializedName("clouds")
@Expose
private Clouds clouds;
@SerializedName("dt")
@Expose
private Long dt;
@SerializedName("sys")
@Expose
private Sys sys;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("cod")
@Expose
private Integer cod;

public Coord getCoord() {
    return coord;
}

public void setCoord(Coord coord) {
    this.coord = coord;
}

public List<Weather> getWeather() {
    return weather;
}

public void setWeather(List<Weather> weather) {
    this.weather = weather;
}

public String getBase() {
    return base;
}

public void setBase(String base) {
    this.base = base;
}

public Main getMain() {
    return main;
}

public void setMain(Main main) {
    this.main = main;
}

public Integer getVisibility() {
    return visibility;
}

public void setVisibility(Integer visibility) {
    this.visibility = visibility;
}

public Wind getWind() {
    return wind;
}

public void setWind(Wind wind) {
    this.wind = wind;
}

public Clouds getClouds() {
    return clouds;
}

public void setClouds(Clouds clouds) {
    this.clouds = clouds;
}

public Long getDt() {
    return dt;
}

public void setDt(Long dt) {
    this.dt = dt;
}

public Sys getSys() {
    return sys;
}

public void setSys(Sys sys) {
    this.sys = sys;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Integer getCod() {
    return cod;
}

public void setCod(Integer cod) {
    this.cod = cod;
}
```

Here is my RecyclerView.Adapter

```
public class Forecast5DaysAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Forecast5DaysAdapter.ForecastHolder> {



List<WeatherData> mWeatherDataList;


public static class ForecastHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView dateOnDate;
    public ImageView weatherOnDate;
    public TextView tempOnDate;
    public TextView windSpeedOnDate;

    public ForecastHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        dateOnDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateOnDate);
        windSpeedOnDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.windSpeedOnDate);
        tempOnDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tempOnDate);
        weatherOnDate = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageOnDate);


    }
}

public Forecast5DaysAdapter(List<WeatherData> mWeatherDataList) {

    this.mWeatherDataList = mWeatherDataList;
}

@Override
public ForecastHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.forecast_card, parent, false);

    final ForecastHolder forecastHolder = new ForecastHolder(view);

    return forecastHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ForecastHolder holder, int position) {

    //FILLING THE CARDS IN RECYCLERVIEW WITH INFORMATION

    holder.dateOnDate.setText(mWeatherDataList.get(position).getDt().toString());
    holder.tempOnDate.setText(mWeatherDataList.get(position).getMain().getTemp().toString());
    holder.windSpeedOnDate.setText(mWeatherDataList.get(position).getWind().getSpeed().toString());
    Picasso.with(holder.weatherOnDate.getContext()).load("http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + mWeatherDataList.get(position).getWeather().get(position).getIcon() + ".png").into(holder.weatherOnDate);

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the class I want to display the Recyclerview

```
public class Forecast5Days extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String API_KEY = "HERE IS THE KEY";

private RecyclerView forecastRecycler;
private ArrayList<WeatherData> mWeatherData;
private Forecast5DaysAdapter forecast5DaysAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_forecast_5_days);

    forecastRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.forecast_5_daysRecycler);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    forecastRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    final Forecast5DaysAdapter forecast5DaysAdapter = new Forecast5DaysAdapter(mWeatherData);

    forecastRecycler.setAdapter(forecast5DaysAdapter);



    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String cityName = intent.getStringExtra("cityName");

    if (!cityName.isEmpty()) {
        Call<WeatherData> call = RetrofitBuilderHelper.weatherAPI.getForecast5Days(cityName, "ru", "metric", API_KEY);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<WeatherData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<WeatherData> call, Response<WeatherData> response) {

                    //????????????????

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<WeatherData> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Forecast5Days.this, "Something went wrong with request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        });

    } else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Forecast5Days.this, "Something went wrong with intent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `onResponse` should be like this

```
   call.enqueue(new Callback<WeatherData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<WeatherData> call, Response<WeatherData> response) {

           if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body != null) {
                WeatherData data = response.body();
           }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<WeatherData> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Forecast5Days.this, "Something went wrong with request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
```

Also your `Call` is `Call<WeatherData>` which will give you a single object. If you want a list of objects your call should be `Call<List<WeatherData>>`

I think you are looking to pass `Weather`instead of `WeatherData` so your `onResponse` should look like

```
      call.enqueue(new Callback<WeatherData>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<WeatherData> call, Response<WeatherData> response) {

       if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body != null) {
            WeatherData data = response.body();
            List<Weather> weatherList = data.getWeatherList(); 
           //Pass this list to your adapter
       }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<WeatherData> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Forecast5Days.this, "Something went wrong with request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was really my mistake, I should have looked to Listitem POJO, not to root object

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON return is a List not only a Single WeatherData Object.
So all you should have to do is a cange of the Expected return value.
Try this:

```
Call<List<WeatherData>> call = RetrofitBuilderHelper.weatherAPI.getForecast5Days(cityName, "ru", "metric", API_KEY);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<WeatherData>>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<List<WeatherData>> call, Response<List<WeatherData>> response) {
    forecastRecycler.weatherList = response.body();
    forecastRecycler.notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for reply, but the issue was a bit another one.